# 3D z-buffer c# GDI plus

Tags: c#, 3d, render, gdi

Im writting very simple 3d engine in c# and GDI+, just for render some models (I think Directx or OpenGL is like shovel to eat soup). So far I have succesfully implemented drawing Wireframe of my model, but next step is of course Faces. And there is my problem, for now I just project my 3d points to 2d point and then drawn it using simple 
for each face`g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, projected_points);` and for wireframe its ok.

It is possible to calculate overlapping part of polygon? and then draw FilledPolygon,
Or better idea is drawing pixel by pixel and if z-buffer of my pixel is further then set new pixel.

If first option is possible, which one is faster (for implement and calculating)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But at that point you might as well just start using directx or opengl, which would do all of that for you.

Comment: I will one up your analogy about DirectX, your approach is too far in the other direction, it is like trying to widdle a soup spoon from a stick when you have a drawer full of silverware right next to you.

Comment: yup, maybe ur right but project Im working on is more to learn something new, my question wasnt "have i use DirectX or no" but which option of theses will be better, faster and so on. Anyway thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to calculate overlapping part of polygon? and then draw FilledPolygon, Or 
>   better idea is drawing pixel by pixel and if z-buffer of my pixel is further then set 
>   new pixel.
>
> If first option is possible, which one is faster (for implement and calculating)?

Yes, it is possible. You can test every polygon with every other of your list. The complexity depends on the type of the polygon (of course, it's easiest with triangles). But the performance may drop drastically with high count of polygons. And even if you find the overlapping areas, you will need to interpolate colors, or texture coordinates (if you plan to use such). Also I'm not sure about the API you use for drawing, but GDI doesn't support fill polygon with interpolated colors.

I have heard that this was the approach used in 3d graphics before inventing the Z buffer. :)

I once tried to realize similar project and used Z-buffer + my own routine to fill triangles with interpolated colors (which uses the Z-buffer). I drawed directly to a GDI bitmap's pixel data buffer. Then after all polygons has been rendered, I bitblt'ed the result to the screen.